# Finitely generated module over Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read that these two proposition are equivalent:

- $R$ is a noetherian ring;
- Every submodule of a finitely generated $R-$module is finitely generated.

While I was thinking about it I made the reasoning below, that leads me to an incorrect conclusion, so I must be wrong somewhere. I hope someone can explain me, thank you in advance.

Calling $M$ the $R-$module, we have $M\simeq R/\mathfrak{i_1}\oplus \dots \oplus R/\mathfrak{i_n}$, so it's clear that if $R$ is noetherian, so is $M$; however if $R/\mathfrak{i_1}\oplus \dots \oplus R/\mathfrak{i_n}$ is noetherian for some ideals $\mathfrak{i_1},\dots , \mathfrak{i_n}$, then $R$ is not necessarily noetherian. That means that the fact that $M$ is noetherian doesn't imply that $R$ is noetherian too.

For example, I let the ring of polynomials $\Bbb R[T_1,T_2,\dots ]$ act on the group $\Bbb R^2$, with $T_im=0\; \forall i,\forall \;m\in \Bbb R^2$. I obtain a module which is isomorphic to $\Bbb R[T_1,T_2,\dots ]/(T_1,T_2,\dots)\oplus \Bbb R[T_1,T_2,\dots ]/(T_1,T_2,\dots)$, which is in fact $\Bbb R^2$. This module is noetherian since every sumbodule is a subspace of dimension $1$ but clearly $\Bbb R[T_1,T_2,\dots ]$ is not.

Comment: Not every finitely generated $R$-module can be decomposed as $R/\mathfrak{i_1}\oplus \dots \oplus R/\mathfrak{i_n}$.

Comment: $M$ is supposed to be finitely generated

Comment: I don't see what you are asking. In your example, $\Bbb R[T_1,T_2,\ldots]$ is a finitely generated module over itself, but the ideal generated by the $T_i$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: The point is that I apparently have a noetherian module over a non noetherian ring, and for the equivalence of that two proposition this is impossible

Comment: If you want a Noetherian module, over a non-Noetherian ring, the easy way to construct one is to take the zero module. (Of course the theorem you cite says nothing about the non-existence of Noetherian modules for non-Noetherian rings.)

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm being dull, but if that two propositions are equivalent, doesn't that mean that if a $R-$module is finitely generated and noetherian then $R$ is noetherian?

Comment: It means, that if **every** submodule of every finitely generated module is finitely generated, then $R$ is Noetherian.

Comment: So the two proposition I wrote above are not equivalent for real, right?

Comment: Those two statements **are** equivalent; what baffles me is why you think your example contradicts that.

Comment: In the second preposition is written **a finitely generated module**, not **every finitely generated module**, so I was thinking that it was sufficient the existence of a noetherian $R-$module to imply that $R$ was noetherian

Comment: However you made the concept clear, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

$R$ is an $R-$ module with respect itself so if it has unity then it will be finitely generated then by hypothesis you have that each sub module of $R$ is finitely generated.

You can observe that each ideal $I$ of $R$ is an $R-$ submodule of $R$ so it will be finitely generated, then there exists a finite number of elements $a_1,\dots, a_n$ such that

$I=(a_1,\dots , a_n)$

So $R$ is a noetherian ring.

Now we suppose that $R$ is a noetherian ring. If $f_1,\dots, f_n$ are generators of $M$ then you can define

$\psi: R\times \dots \times R\to M$ such that for each $(r_1,\dots r_n)$ you have that

$\psi(r_1,\dots , r_n):=r_1 f_1+\dots +\dots r_nf_n$

The map is surjective so by first homomorphism theorem you have that

$M\cong (R\times \dots \times R)/ ker(\psi)$

It is easily prove that if $R$ is a noetherian ring then $R\times \dots \times R$ is such that each its submodule is finitely generated.

Each submodule of $(R\times \dots \times R)/ K$ is finetly generated where $K$ is submodule of $R\times \dots \times R$ so you have finished.

Comment: Thank you what you said is clear, however in my example I don't have a regular module (i.e. a ring considered as a module over itself), I have $\Bbb R ^2$ considered as a $\Bbb R [T_1,T2\dots]-$module